Sorry we ran into an issue. Details: undefined is not an object(evaluating 't.iconUrl') in iOS
I am getting the Sorry we ran into an issue. Details: undefined is not an object(evaluating 't.iconUrl') in the iOS release app downloaded from the App Store. But after closing the error the app worked as expected. This project is developed in React Native. The iconUrl is not declared in my code.

Has anyone faced this issue? I appreciate your help.
